# Compare two generic Lists

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Hi ,how I can compare two *Lists*, the first type `ICollections <T>` the other `List<T>`
see if they contain the same records
using **Linq**

Comment: Do you want to know the intersection of the two lists or if the two lists both have the same items.  Also, will the records have an ID or do you just want to check if object A is equal to object B?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `ICollection<T> x` and `List<T> y`...

If order of the records matters:

```
return x.SequenceEqual(y);
```

If order doesn't matter, I think your best option is to skip LINQ and use a `HashSet<T>`:

```
return new HashSet<T>(x).SetEquals(y);
```

Comment: Caveat though: 
ICollection<int> x = new List<int> {1};
List<int> y = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1 };
bool areEqual = new HashSet<int>(y).SetEquals(x); //true

That *may* be what you want, but if you want to know if the items in the lists are the same and the items are in the list the same amount of times, this won't work. Kudos though for learning me about SetEquals. I've never noticed it :)

Comment: A good point (note that an `Intersect()`-based solution suffers the same fate). If duplicates must be preserved, I'd either sort each list and use `SequenceEquals()` or group by element and use `SetEquals()` on item/count pairs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code depending on whether sequence is important or not :

```
        ICollection<int> collection1 = new List<int> { 5, 1, 6, 7, 3 };
        List<int> collection2 = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6, 7, 3 };

        bool considerSequence = true; // sequence is important
        bool areEquael;

        if (considerSequence)
        {
            areEquael = collection1.SequenceEqual(collection2);
        }
        else
        {
            areEquael = collection1.OrderBy(val => val).SequenceEqual(
                collection2.OrderBy(val => val));
        }
```

As suggested by other colleagues also consider using `HashSet<T>`. Just take into account that `HashSet` is available only starting from **.NET Framework 3.5**.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Guid> lst = new List<Guid>();
    List<Guid> lst1 = new List<Guid>();
    bool result = false;

    if (lst.Count == lst1.Count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!lst[i].Equals(lst1[i]))
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }

    if (result)
    {
        Response.Write("List are same");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("List are not same");
    }
```

use this type of concept....

OR

```
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();
    lst.Add(1);
    lst.Add(51);
    lst.Add(65);
    lst.Add(786);
    lst.Add(456);
    List<int> lst1 = new List<int>();
    lst1.Add(786);
    lst1.Add(1);
    lst1.Add(456);
    lst1.Add(65);
    lst1.Add(51);
    bool result = false;

    if (lst.Count == lst1.Count)
    {
        result = lst.Union(lst1).Count() == lst.Count;
    }

    if (result)
    {
        Response.Write("list are same");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("list are not same");
    }
```

try this one also.....

Comment: This assumes that the order of the lists is exactly the same, not just the items in the list. I think the original question was just about set identity.

Answer (score 0):

```
ICollection<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 6, 7, 8, 9 };

bool contains = list1.Any(e => list2.Any(d => d.Equals(e)));
```