# Generic method to compare 2 strongly typed list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, compare

I have the following method that compares 2 list (of the same type) and returns the differences. How do I make this method accept lists of any type?

```
var differences = list1.Where(x => list2.All(x1 => x1.Name != x.Name))
            .Union(list2.Where(x => list1.All(x1 => x1.Name != x.Name)));
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462870/compare-two-generic-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the difference between two sets (with order independency and multiplicity independency), you can use: [`HashSet<T>.SymmetricExceptWith(IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetSymmetricDifference<T>(IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    HashSet<T> result = new HashSet<T>(list1, comparer);
    result.SymmetricExceptWith(list2);
    return result;
}
```

In your case, to use it:

```
var difference = GetSymmetricDifference(list1, list2, new MyComparer());
```

With a custom comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{
    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        return x.Name.Equals(y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
    {
        return obj.Name == null ? 0 : obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var differences = list1.Except(list2).Union(list2.Except(list1));
```